# Стал медленнее работать cmd, powershell а так же терминал в pyCharm в чём причина?

Tags: cmd, pycharm, powershell, командная-строка

Сегодня заметил что любая команда в cmd и powershell стала работать как будто с задержкой в 30 сек, а после перезагрузки пк всё работает как раньше но через 15 мин, и опять начинается задержка. А так же я создаю бота и он тоже через 15 мин работы компьютера начиет отвечать с задержкой, я его запускаю через bat файл. Может знает кто в чём причина?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Когда я перезагружаю комп командная строка отвечает отлично 
    К примеру команда pip
После перезагрузки она сразу начинает скачивать библиотеку
А когда  проходит примерно 15 минут таже команда pip будет скачивается после 30 секундной задержки    
С чем связано не понятно, вот я и хочу узнать может у кого то была такая же проблема и он расскажет как её решить
Или просто кто то знает как её решить